# First INSERT, then - if OK - DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This SQL SERVER 2005 statement first deletes 18 record ordering them by `FIELD1 ASC`, then inserts the same 18 records in a clone table:

```
WITH  q AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 18 *
        FROM    pippo
        ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC /* You may want to add ORDER BY here */
        )
DELETE
FROM    q
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO TableNew
```

Please help me to convert the previous statement in order to first `INSERT`, and `THEN` - `IF INSERT` HAS BEEN OK - delete the same 18 records; I've just tried but the following code gives the error,

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near 'INSERTED'.`

```
WITH  q AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 18 *
        FROM    pippo
        ORDER BY ID_OL ASC /* You may want to add ORDER BY here */
        )
insert into tablenew select * from q OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO TABLENEW
```

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: no it's not, it also available for operations like u/i/d

Comment: @All -- whoops, I had no idea about that, sorry.  Deleted.

Comment: i would do this with a post trigger.  if the record is inserted, then in the trigger, delete the duplicate from the original table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @some_temp_table table (ID_OL int)

WITH  q AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 18 *
        FROM    pippo
        ORDER BY ID_OL ASC /* You may want to add ORDER BY here */
        )
insert into minnie
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID_OL INTO @some_temp_table
select * from q

delete from pippo where ID_OL in (select ID_OL from @some_temp_table)
```

another version

```
set xact_abort on

declare @filter table (ID_OL int primary key)

insert into @filter (ID_OL)
SELECT TOP 18 ID_OL
FROM pippo
ORDER BY ID_OL ASC

begin transaction

insert into minnie 
select * from pippo where ID_OL in (select ID_OL from @filter)

delete from pippo where ID_OL in (select ID_OL from @filter)

commit transaction
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Q or DELETE FROM Q ??

Comment: select from q and output inserted.* into some table.
then you need to delete this data from another table (pippo?)

Comment: you can start a transaction by `begin transaction` if you want both your statements in one transaction. I don't know if it's possible to make insert/delete by one statement (only delete/insert)

Comment: I need to delete from the source table (pippo), after having inserted into the target table (minnie)

Comment: i've changed an answer, may be it helps. Also, you can write this query without `OUTPUT` at all. First you get top 18 rows and insert it into @Temp_Table, then you inserting that rows into minnee and then you delete it from pippo

Comment: Don't you think that your final DELETE statement is too heavy?  Some_temp_table grows, if source table has for example one million records.

Comment: Your FILTER solutions is very nice.

Comment: btw I've changed it a little bit. First, I've added transaction. Second, I've added `primary key` into `@filter` table, otherwise it could be sloooow

Comment: Is there any way to avoid deletion if, for any reason, INSERT fails?

Comment: well if it raises an exception then transaction will fail. if you don't want to rely on that, you can check `ERROR_MESSAGE` and if it's not null then rollback a transaction. But, I like solution with `xact_abort` - it allows you to write compact code

Comment: Are you able to modify the "another version" avoiding deletions in case of insert failures?

Comment: it already modified. If `insert` failures then it will raise exception, and transaction will be rolled back because `xact_abort` instruction is set to `on`.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I have not seen your changes :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into temptable
SELECT TOP 18 * FROM  pippo ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC

if(@@ROWCOUNT = 18)
BEGIN
WITH  q AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 18 *
        FROM    pippo
        ORDER BY ID_OL ASC /* You may want to add ORDER BY here */
        )

delete from q 
END
```

Comment: I think using @@ROW_COUNT could lead to some bugs, f.e. sp can have `set nocount on` in it.

Comment: set nocount on is not related to @@ROWCOUNT its jsut shows the number of rows affected message

Comment: yes, you right :) `@@rowcount` could lead to some bugs, but it's not related to `set nocount on`

Comment: what error since all statements will be in the same scope it wont lead to any error

Comment: I did not understand if the code is correct and usable, or not: what type of bugs could I encounter if I use @@rowcount for example??